# How can I create a Symfony form base class for fields used on every entity?

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to come up with a way to create a 'base form' that contains fields used on every entity, i.e. `id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, etc.

I want to either extend the base form when I create a new form or easily include it in each new form I make. I can't find much documentation on it, is this a common thing to do?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it as it would make that single element a dependency of everything you make.

Comment: I have a base entity class which contains those fields, if I did have a form which was different I just wouldn't extend it in that case.

Comment: Oh right, I read it as entity rather than form. To make a base form just make the form the way you normally would and then extend that instead of `AbstractType` and overwrite what ever you need to (eg, `getName`, `buildForm`, etc). Then in your child form you can just call `parent::buildForm($builder, $options)` in your `buildForm`.